# Spring boot JPA + MySQL throws error

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to configure Spring boot and JPA in my application. After searching the Internet, I have configured my app like below (adding only relevant portion of code):

**`pom.xml:`**

```
        <!-- JPA Starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${version.spring.boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mysql.driver}</version>
        </dependency>
```

**`application.properties:`**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**`Application configuration Java class:`**

```
@StatelessBusinessService
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = { "com.org.ist.module.service" }
)
@EnableScheduling
public class MyServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyServiceApplication.class);
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MyServiceApplication.class);
    }
```

And below is the error which I get when I execute `mvn spring-boot:run` from terminal:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Maybe I have missed some simple configuration?

Comment: Does your project have a hibernate.properties or persistence.xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding the below annotation to spring boot application class to exclude auto configuration of data source.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Many thanks Anil :) I knew, I missed some simple config! May be you want to explain a bit about why one needs to exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class though?